# Working hours crossing midnight

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with working program for employees like this:

```
| column      | type                |
| id          | {int}               |
| day_of_week | (int 1{Mon}-7{Sun}) | 
| from_time   | {time H:i:s}        | 
| to_time     | {time H:i:s}        |
| nd          | {enum 0,1}          |
```

I need to do a search will return working persons at current time, all good when time range is from 00:00 to 23:59, but my problem is when a person pick - monday from 23:00 to 04:00 - crossing day, how can i store this fields so i can query it from mysql ?

I solved this with a php hack, for people interested here is the solution:

```
    for ($i=0;$i<=1000000;$i++){
        $to_h = rand(0,23);
        if($to_h<10) $to_h = '0'.$to_h;
        $to_m = rand(0,59);
        if($to_m<10) $to_m = '0'.$to_m;
        $from_h = rand(0,23);
        if($from_h<10) $from_h = '0'.$from_h;
        $from_m = rand(0,59);
        if($from_m<10) $from_m = '0'.$from_m;
        if($to_h<=$from_h){
            if($to_h<$from_h){
                $next=1;
            }elseif($to_h==$from_h){
                if($to_m<=$from_m){
                    $next=1;
                }else{
                    $next=0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $next = 0;
        }
        $db->query("insert into test set day_of_week='".rand(1,7)."', from_time='".$from_h.':'.$from_m."', to_time='".$to_h.':'.$to_m."', nd='".$next."'");
    }
```

And mysql query to search persons working now:

`SELECT *, date_format(now(), '%H:%i:%s') FROM test where day_of_week=2 and ((from_time<=date_format(now(), '%H:%i:%s') and to_time>=date_format(now(), '%H:%i:%s') and nd=0) OR (to_time<=date_format(now(), '%H:%i:%s') and nd=1)) limit 30;`

This query have a very nice response time and i havent noticed any errors in benchmark.
Note: "nd" means Next Day (working hours over midnight of current weekday)

Comment: It will not fit in your table, since the table has only one day column instead of from_day and to_day

Comment: you could change your table structure for use two datetime fields, **start** and **end** and it would be easy to query the data

Comment: In what way are you attempting to query the data? Who is working at a certain time, work hours per week, time ranges when noone is working, ...?

Comment: is daily program, not one time to store it as datetime.

Comment: You should use a `date` type for your the columns instead of int like `datetime`. That way all you will need is a `start_time` and `end_time` column and not worry about storing time and date separately.You can do addition and such with the time using MySQL functions

Comment: SELECT * from program where day=WEEKDAY(curdate()) and from_hour<=hour(now()) and from_minute<=minute(now()) and to_hour>=hour(now()) and to_minute>=minute(now()) - but when to_hour<from_hour is problematic

Comment: I would recommend using start time and end time datetime columns rather than splitting up days, hours, minutes.  It would make your desired query trivial.

Comment: @MikeBrant im not sure i understand your advice, because this program is daily , and is never changing, so your plan is to enter few houndred of rowrs with Y-m-d H-i:00 ?? or ??

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATETIME` for start and end.

Because it's that simple:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) -- time difference in hours
```

Get working persons for point in time:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start AND end
```

Get currently working persons (assuming `NULL` value for `end`):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() > start AND end IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing everything as a number you could derive a to_date with something like `CASE WHEN to_hour < from_hour THEN day + 1 ELSE day`  You could then concatenate your to's together and your for's together and test if NOW is between them (where now is a concatenation of the same form: `CONCAT(day,hour,minute)` Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table>
WHERE
CONCAT(<currentday>,<currenthour>,<currentminute>) BETWEEN CONCAT(day, from_hour, from_minute) AND CONCAT(CASE WHEN to_hour < from_hour THEN day + 1 ELSE day END CASE, to_hour, to_min)
```

There may be a need to cast those ints to chars in order to concat (I can't remember if mysql cares), but with a little screwing around this should allow you to span over days.

Edited to add: 
As I think about this more, because time and hour are two digits it will be necessary to pad those with a 0 when they are a single digit so the CONCAT doesn't fart everything up. That would look something like `CASE WHEN LENGTH(from_hour) = 1 then CONCAT('0', from_hour) else from_hour END CASE` and so on... it makes for one ugly WHERE statement, but it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a need to do this, I would store a duration, rather than an end point. I'd assume that the "day" represents midnight, and I'd store the number of hours and minutes from midnight for the start and end.

```
| column      | type                | comment
| id          | {int}               |
| day_of_week | (int 1{Mon}-7{Sun}) | 
| from_time   | TIME                | time past midnight of dow
| to_time     | TIME                | time past midnight of dow
```

I can use the HOUR and MINUTE functions to extract the hours and minutes from the TIME datatype. ANd I can very easily add the TIME value to a DATE value to get a DATETIME value.

For example, for a row that represents 10PM Tuesday to 6AM Wednesday:

```
 id, day_of_week, from_time, to_time
 42,           2,   '22:00', '30:00'
```

For example, if I was sure the date value I had was a "Tuesday"

```
 SELECT ADDTIME('2014-09-30',t.from_time) AS from_dt
      , ADDTIME('2014-09-30',t.from_time) AS to_dt
   FROM t
  WHERE t.day_of_week = 2
```

Otherwise, I could just a date value of the previous "Sunday"

```
 SELECT ADDTIME('2014-09-28' + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY,t.from_time) AS from_dt
      , ADDTIME('2014-09-28' + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY,t.from_time) AS to_dt
   FROM t
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q: and select query would be like ? lets say now we are on Wed 01:00 , and i need to check persons working now?**

That query would be just a little more involved. From today's date, we'd need to get preceding Sunday, add in the day of week days, and then add in the duration.

To get a "Sunday" date, we could use an expression like this:

```
DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW())+1 DAY
```

We can use that value, and add the number of days and time duration

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.day_of_week
     , t.from_time
     , t.to_time
  FROM t
  JOIN (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW())+1 DAY AS d) d
    ON NOW() >= ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.from_time)
   AND NOW() <  ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.to_time)
```

I'm thinking the stored value of 7 vs 0 for Sunday might be a problem, we'll have to do a little testing and mucking with it.

For testing, we can remove references to `NOW()`, and use an expression that returns a DATETIME we want to test.  We could use a user-defined variable, e.g. `@now`.  (We might need to ensure that gets cast to DATETIME, using a STR_TO_DATE function, e.g. `STR_TO_DATE(@now,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`

(I think the issues are going to crop up on the edge cases, most likely with a 0 and 7 for Sunday.)

For testing, I'd add the DATETIME expressions to the SELECT list, as well as the boolean expression we want to use as a predicate (in the ON or WHERE clause) so we can see what's happening.

```
SET @now = '2014-10-01 04:00'

SELECT t.id
     , t.day_of_week
     , t.from_time
     , t.to_time

     , @now
     , ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.from_time)   AS from_dt
     , ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.to_time)     AS to_dt

     , ( @now >= ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.from_time) AND
         @now <  ADDTIME(d.d + INTERVAL t.day_of_week DAY, t.to_time)
       ) AS is_match

  FROM t
  JOIN (SELECT DATE( @now - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@now)+1 DAY AS d) d
```

Personally, I think I would store Sunday day_of_week value as a 0 (like we do on Unix), but it might turn out that 7 works just fine. We can figure out an expression using either the `DAYOFWEEK` or `WEEKDAY` function, might need to be tweaked a bit.

---

Also need to test periods that span Midnight Monday. day_of_week=7 and to_time > 24 hours, to make sure those also get picked up... we want to be consistent in how we generate the DATETIME, we want to make sure we always "add forward", and don't rollback a week, to_time will have to **larger** that from_time.

The SUBTIME function can subtract, to get a duration, if you need that,

Comment: and select query would be like ? lets say now we are on Wed 01:00 , and i need to check persons working now? Thanks

Comment: @AgapieAurel: NOTE: this is operating on "day of week" repeating schedule, not a particular datetime. Based on the other answers and comments, perhaps I've entirely misunderstood that requirement. That expression to get "midnight" previous Sunday adds muckiness to the query, but if you squint a little, and just see it as "last Sunday", it doesn't look too bad. In the "schedule" table, 6PM Wed could be represented as `day=3 time=18:00`, but it could also be represented as `day=2 time=42:00`.

Comment: We only want one "day_of_week" for a schedule row, so that we can subtract the from_time from the to_time (SUBTIME function) to get the duration between those. If we store two different "day" values, that gets real mucky. You could also not store "day_of_week" at all, and just use "hours past midnight Sunday". With this design, in either case, you do have some ickiness to deal with, getting a from_dt "06:00 Thursday" displayed out of either "30:00 Wednesday", or out of "102:00 Sunday".